# hash and compare password which is saved as hash using SHA1 in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a column of varbinary(max) type and used  a salt of nvarchar(60) type that is generated randomly. I saved the salt in db and saved password using hashbyte(password+ salt).

Now I want to compare user password and authenticate him.

I tried taking his password and running this query--

```
SELECT [email] from admin where 
[password]=HashBytes('SHA1','xxxxxx' +'/KsDnXdU+_a<t19wYCnEi/lxmXmAutR3DVA$#]~dSBskRMB?sb#41+=MFRpE')
```

It is not returning me email. I ran it directly on sql server management studio. But It gave me blank. Why is it so?

When im selecting by email im getting role, this means email is registered.
Is something wrong in my salt or query?

I fixed it. Actualy adding salt directly was causing me a bug, though it was getting added directly and hash was computed and no error was returned from sql server.

When i ran this query

```
Select role from admin where salt='/KsDnXdU+_a<t19wYCnEi/lxmXmAutR3DVA$#]~dSBskRMB?sb#41+=MFRpE'
```

I got no result. I realised, it was some Conversion problem. I used then `Convert(nvarchar(60),'%?r>%Vb+$hUZO8}=38/_J[@q@1mf^rz!V&q~\dLH5nQ&/edR\c[6ya|q$e%r')`

and ran my query as

```
SELECT [email] from admin where 
[password]=HashBytes('SHA1', 'xxxxxx'+Convert(nvarchar(60),'%?r>%Vb+$hUZO8}=38/_J[@q@1mf^rz!V&q~\dLH5nQ&/edR\c[6ya|q$e%r'))
```

This returned me email. I am really not sure why this happened, but using sqlserver 2005, and above query i fixed it. I request moderators, If it is any bug in sql server 2005, please do let other know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same code when reading and when writing:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.admin (email, password, salt)
VALUES(@email,HashBytes('SHA2_512',@password+@salt),@salt);
```

and

```
SELECT email FROM dbo.admin
 WHERE password = HashBytes('SHA2_512',@password+salt);
```

The only difference is that the select references the stored salt instead of a passed in salt.
You also should use the SHA2 algorithm as SHA1 is not secure anymore (http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/sha1-decrypt.aspx). For SHA2_512 your column needs to be 64 bytes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx). You should use the specific length instead of (MAX) if possible.

As Aaron noted, SHA2 is not supported before SQL 2012. You can use a CLR implementation instead. This can get you started: http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2009/09/19/strong-password-hashing-with-sql-server.aspx However, it is using only 256 bits.

Comment: Im locally testing it on sqlserver 2005, but my server has sql server 2008r2. How can i do that? my simple query is not able to yield me email or role using password and its hash

Comment: Good point, @AaronBertrand. I added that remark to my answer.